LIme Survery Multiple choice in table format
enter image description hereCould anyone provide guidance on how to create a table format for multiple-choice questions in LimeSurvey, similar to the one shown in the image? I would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance. Thank you!
I have tried every option possible in array section in Lime survery nothing works :(

The question is tagged “google-forms” but I don’t see any relevance to Forms other than the sample question. Since the question is really about Lime Survey, I think the Forms tag should be deleted.

Does this help Array of Checkboxes in LimeSurvey? From the blog of Peter Bloomfield.
